# Can you decide an ngIf for a singular parameter on a component?

Tags: html, angularjs, if-statement

Ive been told this may not work out-of-the-box with Angular but I wanted to check if anyone else had an idea. I am attempting the following:

My *preferred solution* is:

```
<ds-checkbox *ngIf="maxSelectAll != undefined; then showTooltip else '//STAYHERE'"
     id="data-table-select-all-checkbox"
     [checked]="allClicked"
     (checkedChange)="_handleAllClick()"
     [disabled]="selectCheckBoxesDisabled"
 ></ds-checkbox>

 <ng-template #showTooltip
     [dsTooltip]="'Only the first ' + maxSelectAll + ' ' + nameForTotal + ' will be selected'"
 ></ng-template>
```

The *working solution* is:

```
<ds-checkbox *ngIf="maxSelectAll == undefined; else showTooltip"
     id="data-table-select-all-checkbox"
     [checked]="allClicked"
     (checkedChange)="_handleAllClick()"
     [disabled]="selectCheckBoxesDisabled"
 ></ds-checkbox>
 <ng-template #showTooltip
     id="data-table-select-all-checkbox"
     [dsTooltip]="'Only the first ' + maxSelectAll + ' ' + nameForTotal + ' will be selected'"
     [checked]="allClicked"
     (checkedChange)="_handleAllClick()"
     [disabled]="selectCheckBoxesDisabled"
 ></ng-template>
```

I would rather not duplicate code if possible, but I am not seeing another option in angular. Is there a way to add only a single parameter to the checkbox without needing to redo all of the parameters that will exist anyways? As of now, my first example will see maxSelectAll as undefined and skip all of the parameters below it (my 'STAYHERE' note for id, checked, checkedChange, disabled).

If this cannot be done, no worries. Thank you for your time!

EDIT: Another attempt?

```
<ds-checkbox *ngIf="maxSelectAll == undefined; then standards;
              else standards; then showTooltip">
</ds-checkbox>

 <ng-template #standards
     id="data-table-select-all-checkbox"
     [checked]="allClicked"
     (checkedChange)="_handleAllClick()"
     [disabled]="selectCheckBoxesDisabled"
 ></ng-template>

 <ng-template #showTooltip
     [dsTooltip]="'Only the first ' + maxSelectAll + ' ' + nameForTotal + ' will be selected'"
 ></ng-template>
```

TLDR:
I would like:

```
<ds-checkbox
     id="data-table-select-all-checkbox"
     [dsTooltip]="'Only the first ' + maxSelectAll + ' ' + nameForTotal + ' will be selected'"
     [checked]="allClicked"
     (checkedChange)="_handleAllClick()"
     [disabled]="selectCheckBoxesDisabled"
 ></ds-checkbox>
```

Where[dsTooltip] can be added conditionally to the checkbox.

Comment: It seems my understanding of ng-template is off, as you have to pass in the <ds-checkbox> to it. That I think breaks my ideas :( Still hoping there is something out there of course

Comment: Doesnt ternary operator in [dsTooltip] solve your problem?

Comment: I think the very existence of the `[dsTooltip]` prop binding is what he wants to be conditional - not have it bind to a particular value regardless, but entirely remove the binding in certain cases without needing to duplicate every other binding on `<ds-checkbox>`

Comment: ill add a TLDR that will make it more clear